# Steps to transfer content database of sharepoint 2013 site from production to dev server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database, content-migration

Is it Possible to transfer my production SP Site content DB to Development server where both the server is bind with different AD.

Here In the Developement server I cant find Production Farm Administrator and site admin.

Can any one suggest me the correct steps to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it Possible to transfer my production SP Site content DB to Development server where both the server is bind with different AD.**

Yes, It's possible , In Dev You should use the SPfarm and site admin of the current environment,  no need to the same account at production.

**In the Development server I can't find Production Farm Administrator and site admin**

No need to use the same production service accounts, you should use the corresponding service accounts in Dev environment.

**Steps**

I did the following steps to migrate a content database from one environment to another that worked successfully .

- First of all, you should make sure that the SharePoint Build number of Dev environment must be matched with the build number of the production environment, to make sure that check.

  - [Find the latest Cumulative Update / Farm Patch Level that has been installed in a SharePoint Farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-the-latest-cu-farm-patch-level-that-already-installed-in-your-sharepoint-farm/)
  - [This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/05/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/)
- In production, Take a backup of the content database via SQl management Studio.
- In Dev, Create A web application , Site collection.
- In Dev, Dismount the the web application content database , via this command

`Dismount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentdBName>"`

- In Dev, via SQL Management Studio , Restore the content database.
- In Dev, Mount it to the created web application,

`Mount-SPContentDatabase "<ContentDb>" -DatabaseServer "<DbServer>" -WebApplication http://SiteName`

- In Dev, Change Site collection administrator for the web application to avoid the access permission issue. by going to site Setting > Site Collection Administrator > Set the site admin account in Dev.

For more details check [Restore / Migrate a SharePoint Web Application to another farm from SQL Database Backup](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: I am getting technical error  while loading the page And while checking the files I found "UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized". I already update site collection admin and clear blob cache. Any Idea why I am getting this error?